# How to iterate and update documents over lucene documents?

Tags: java, lucene

I have simple code for iterate and update documents. Index is too large – millions of documents, 10-20gb.
This is an pseudocode:

```
liveDocs = MultiFields.getLiveDocs(reader);
docsEnum = MultiFields.getTermDocsEnum(reader, 
  MultiFields.getLiveDocs(reader), field, bytesRef);
while ((doc = docsEnum.nextDoc()) != DocsEnum.NO_MORE_DOCS) {
  oldDocument = reader.document(doc);
  // some updates
  writer.updateDocument(term, newDocument, analyzer);
  break;
  // simple flush policy
  if(doc % 10000 == 0){
    writer.commit();
  }
}
```

DocsEnum worked correctly with reader, which it initialised. But related to reader index segments(files) does't removed before reader is opened, and index size is doubled each update iteration. After day of work, index size is terabytes!
If close all readers and writes, and reopen index - old segments will be removed.
How to correctly iterate & update documents without disk files leak?

I use java 1.7, lucene 4.8

Comment: Are you sure you are finding documents to delete with `term`?  Try running a search against it, like:  `TopDocs docs = indexSearcher.search(new TermQuery(term), 10);`, and make sure the results are what you are expecting.

Comment: Example correct works for data manipulation. But garbage (lucene previous segment files) does not collected.

Comment: I rewrote example using `IndexSearcher.search()` && `IndexSearcher.searchAfter()` - now old segments correctly cleaned. Maybe this is the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution that I find - use IndexSearcher.search() && IndexSearcher.searchAfter().

Something like this:

```
// inside iterator
TopDocs docs;
if (lastScore == null) {
    docs = searcher.search(query, filter, limit, Sort.INDEXORDER, false, false);
} else {
    docs = searcher.searchAfter(lastScore, query, filter, limit, Sort.INDEXORDER, false, false);
}
lastScore = docs.scoreDocs[docs.scoreDocs.length - 1];
for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : docs.scoreDocs) {
    Document = searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc, fields));
}
```